# New to F# and Don't Know How to Fix FS0025 error

Tags: f#, ocaml, f#-3.0

I'm struggling trying to teach myself F# (my very first functional programming language) by building a very important app (or trying to) that will record user input and write to a JSON file (or eventually, a database) the outcomes of requests for help made by poor trafficking survivors to all the anti-trafficking charities/NGO's in the US. I keep getting this error, after trying everything I could think of to make sure that all possible cases for the pattern in question were considered. I don't know how to fix it, and I really can't use any error suppression on this app. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, as I have no one else to reach out to for any help and support. Here is my code from the TerminalBuilder.fs file:

```
namespace Nonprofits

module TerminalBuilder =
    open System
    open System.IO
    open Nonprofits.Types

    let rec caller():Caller =
        printfn "Are you reporting as an advocate on behalf of someone else or for yourself?"
        printfn " 1 for Advocate"
        printfn " 2 for Self"
        let answer = Console.ReadLine()
        match answer with
        | "1" -> Advocate
        | "2" -> ClientOrVictim 
        | _ -> printfn "Invalid Entry"
               caller()

    let specialneeds():Set<Disability> =
        let rec spnds(s:Set<Disability>): Set<Disability> =
            printfn "Do you/the person on whose behalf you're reporting have any disabling conditions?"
            printfn " 1 for Learning Disability"
            printfn " 2 for Physical Disability"
            printfn " 3 for Mental Health Issues"
            printfn " 4 for Substance Addiction Issues"
            printfn " 5 for Pregnancy-Related Limitations"
            printfn " 6 for Chronic Illness"
            printfn " 7 for Don't KNow/Undiagnosed"
            printfn " Enter 'Exit' for None"
            let answer = Console.ReadLine()
            match answer.Trim().ToLower() with
            | "exit" -> s
            | _ -> 
                let sn =
                    match answer.Trim().ToLower() with
                    | "1" -> Some LearningDisabled
                    | "2" -> Some PhysicallyDisabled
                    | "3" -> Some MentalIllness
                    | "4" -> Some SubstanceAddiction
                    | "5" -> Some Pregnancy
                    | "6" -> Some ChronicIllness
                    | "7" -> Some Undiagnosed
                    | "exit" -> printfn "No disabling conditions"
                                None
                match sn with
                | None -> spnds(s)
                | Some (x) -> spnds(s.Add(x))
        spnds(new Set<Disability> ([]))
```

And here is my types file, Nonprofits.fs:

```
namespace Nonprofits

open System.Collections

module Types =

    type NgoType =
        | HomelessShelter
        | DVShelter
        | TraffickingVictimSafehouse
        | TraffickingSurvivorAftercare // gamut of legal, housing, clothing, food, medical, reintegration, etc.
        | FoodPantries
        | ClothingAssistance
        | FreeMedicalDentalClinic

    type Ngo = Ngo of NgoType * string 


    type Caller =
        | ClientOrVictim 
        | Advocate

    and CallerStatus =
        | VictimServicesAdvocate of Caller
        | DVvictim of Caller
        | SexTraffickingSurvivor of Caller
        | HomelessVictim of Caller
        | NaturalDisasterVictim of Caller
        | GeneralPovertyVictim of Caller

    and Disability =
        | Pregnancy 
        | PhysicallyDisabled 
        | LearningDisabled 
        | MentalIllness 
        | SubstanceAddiction 
        | ChronicIllness 
        | Undiagnosed 

    and SpecialNeeds = SpecialNeeds of Set<Disability>

    type UnmetNeeds =
        | TraffickingSafebed
        | DVsafebed  
        | Housing
        | Clothing
        | Food
        | Legal 
        | Medical
        | Dental
        | Vision
        | DrugRehab
        | TraumaCare
        | PsychiatricCare
        | SkillsTraining
        | EducationHelp
        | JobPlacement
        | EconomicSupport

    type CallerRequest =
        | TraffickingVictimAftercare of Set<UnmetNeeds>
        | PovertyVictimCare of Set<UnmetNeeds>

    type Followup =
        | SocialWorkerFollowup of Help
        | CallerSelfDirected of Help

    and Help =
        | Helped //fully helped with everything caller needed
        | ExhaustedOptions // exhausted resources and still not helped
        | WrongHelp //i.e. caller offered smoking cessation counseling when caller needed sex trafficking aftercare
        | NotHelped of Followup
        | GivenReferral of ReferredToNextNgo

    and ReferredToNextNgo = ReferredToNextNgo of Followup * Ngo

    type CallOutcome =
        | CallerHelped
        | CallerNotHelped of Followup
        | CallerReferred of ReferredToNextNgo


    type Call = Call of Caller * CallerRequest * CallOutcome
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

> C:\Users\3CU1501060\Documents\Projects\DUandTypesPractice\DUandTypesPractice\TerminalBuilder.fs(27,27): Warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '"a"' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s). (FS0025) (DUandTypesPractice)

Comment: If you just want the answer, this line `match answer.Trim().ToLower() with` has an incomplete match.  Since you're matching on a string you have to use the `_` pattern to capture the rest of the options.

Comment: I already tried that but it still isn't working for me. I got another error and I am at a total loss for how to fix it.

Comment: @mydogisbox, nothing I have tried has worked for me. In doing what you said, I get the error "Expression was expected to have type 'Disability option' but has type unit." I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73180/discussion-between-super-j-and-mydogisbox).

Comment: This question is sufficiently nuanced to not be a duplicate. A little cleanup would improve it, but otherwise it's legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you pattern match

```fsharp
      let sn =
                match answer.Trim().ToLower() with
                | "1" -> Some LearningDisabled
                | "2" -> Some PhysicallyDisabled
                | "3" -> Some MentalIllness
                | "4" -> Some SubstanceAddiction
                | "5" -> Some Pregnancy
                | "6" -> Some ChronicIllness
                | "7" -> Some Undiagnosed
                | "exit" -> printfn "No disabling conditions"
                            None
```

```

you check "1", "2", ... "exit", but there are other values, for example "a", you need to add another case

```
| answer -> //do something
```

in your case maybe

```
| answer -> printfn "not supported answer %A" answer
            None // or retry?
```

the compiler is helping you, telling you "what happen if user choose 'a'"?

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I did try a similar work-around, adding this to my cases:

| _ -> printfn "Invalid Entry"
        None

That seemed to work until I got to the point where I had to finish the deconstructors in Program.fs. For some reason, there is a logic error being thrown. If I enter "1...7", I get the prompts for answering those questions and the answer not registering, unless if I choose the one for no disabling conditions.  Logic errors are even harder to pin down here because there's a lot going on in my code.